# Multiple same elements in the list, how to display only once, no duplicates?

Tags: c#

My List contains multiple subjects, but some of them are the same. How to display all of them but without repetitions?

```
public class Subject
{
    public string SubjectName { get; set; }

    public Subject(string subjectName)
    {
        this.SubjectName = subjectName;
    }
}
```

```
List<Subject> listOfSubjects = new List<Subject>();
string subject = "";
Console.WriteLine("Enter the name of the subject");
subject = Console.ReadLine();
listofSubjects.Add(new Subject(subject));
string pastSubject = "";                   
foreach (Subject sub in listOfSubjects)
{
    if (sub.SubjectName != pastSubject)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(sub.SubjectName);
    }
    pastSubject = sub.SubjectName;
}
```

Comment: Looks like your code already contains an attempt for that. Didn't it work? Can you describe the symptoms?

Comment: @GolezTrol this code will display all subjects form the list including repetitions.

Comment: If you don't want repetitions then you can use a data structure that takes care of it for you like a  HashSet<T> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @JessedeWit Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'EqualityComparer<Subject>'because it is not a delegate type.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Linq` then you can use [GroupBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netframework-4.7.2) to get the distinct `Subject`s by name.

```
var distinctList = listOfSubjects
                     .GroupBy(s => s.SubjectName)    // group by names
                     .Select(g => g.First());        // take the first group

foreach (var subject in distinctList)
{
    Console.WriteLine(subject.SubjectName);
}
```

This method returns `IEnumerable<Subject>`, ie a collection of the actual `Subject` class.

I created a [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Sf61e6).

Answer (score 1):

One solution can be to build a `IEqualityComparer<Subject>` for the Subject class. Below is code for it.

```
public class SubjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<Subject>
{
    public bool Equals(Subject x, Subject y)
    {
        if (x == null && y == null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (x == null || y == null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return x.SubjectName == y.SubjectName;
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Subject obj)
    {
        return obj.SubjectName.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then just call the System.Linq Distinct function on it supplying the IEqualityComparer instance.

```
List<Subject> distinctSubjects = listOfSubjects.Distinct(new SubjectComparer()).ToList();
```

The resultant distinctSubjects list is Distinct.

Answer (score 0):

You can get distinct subject names with

```
var distinctSubjectNames = listOfSubjects
    .Select(s => s.SubjectName)
    .Distinct();
foreach (string subjectName in distinctSubjectNames) {
        Console.WriteLine(subjectName);
}
```